# Unable to configure nrf24l01+ with Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ model.  I also bought a few nrf24l01+ modules.

I hooked up one of the nrf24l01+ modules to my RPi with these connections:

```
RPi    | nrf24l01+
-------|----------
3.3    |  VCC
GND    |  GND
GPIO8  |  CSN
GPIO17 |  CE
GPIO10 |  MOSI
GPIO09 |  MISO
GPIO11 |  SCK
```

I downloaded the BLavery library for RPi from here: https://github.com/BLavery/lib_nrf24 .  I then moved the file `lib_nrf24.py` to my working directory at `~/projects/helloworld/lib_nrf24.py`.

I then created a file called `~/projects/helloworld/receiver.py` and placed the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1],[0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0,17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()
```

When I run the command `python3 ~/projects/helloworld/receiver.py`, I get this output:

```
STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     =
 0xfdfdfdfdfd 0xfefefefefc
RX_ADDR_P2-5     =
0xf8
0xf9
0xf9
0xf9

TX_ADDR          =
 0xfdfdfdfdfd
RX_PW_P0-6       =
0x00
0x0c
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00

EN_AA            =
0x0f

EN_RXADDR        =
0x00

RF_CH            =
0x1f

RF_SETUP         =
0x00

CONFIG           =
0x03

DYNPD/FEATURE    =
0x03
0x01

Data Rate        = 1MBPS
Model            = nRF24L01
CRC Length       = Disabled
PA Power         = PA_MIN
```

My question is why does the output show `RX_ADDR_P0-1 = 0xfdfdfdfdfd 0xfefefefefc` when I wrote `[0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]`, and why does the output show  `RF_CH = 0x1f` when I wrote `radio.setChannel(0x76)`?

I noticed that BLavery stopped supporting the lib_nrf24 library a few months before my RPi 3 B+ was released.  Would this have anything to do with my problem?  Is there another practical way to use the nrf24l01 module with my RPi 3 B+?

Note: this is part of my investigation into why the RPi 3 B + is not receiving any payload from my arduinos that are transmitting with an nrf24l01 module.  I got two arduinos to talk to each other with nrf24l01. So my next step is to get arduino to RPi working.

Comment: Can you please consider this tutorial: https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/1151/tutorial-raspberry-pi-nrf24l01-direct-connection

Comment: Thanks, I'm stuck on step 4 where it asks to enter the directory `Raspberry/librf24-bcm/`. I don't see that directory in the tmrh20 library or the `Raspberry-master` that I downloaded in Step 3.

Comment: You unziped it!?

Comment: That's correct, I unzipped  `https://github.com/mysensors/Raspberry/archive/master.zip` and don't see any `librf24-bcm`

Comment: https://github.com/mysensors/Raspberry can you follow instructions from here for nrf they added other things

Comment: If you get everything let me know and i ll post the correct answer

Comment: I'm following the instructions here https://www.mysensors.org/build/raspberry .  And the `sudo mysgw` gives an output similar to what the guide outlines.  So my next question is what channels, addresses etc.... is the Raspberry Pi listening on?  For example, I have an arduino also equipped with an nrf24l01+.   What values do I provide for `radio.openWritingPipe(<addressvalue>)` and `radio.setChannel(<channelNumber>)` in my arduino sketch file such that it will successfully transmit data to the RPi?

Comment: the address which u use in arduino http://robotix.ah-oui.org/user_docs/dos11/NRF24L01-tutorial.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89890/discussion-between-john-and-shubhendu-yadav).